# How to enable the DVD Writer `Passthrough` checkbox in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I need to burn a DVD from Windows 8 inside VirtualBox.  The drive is called `Host Drive TSSTcorp DVDWBD`.  I have many times in the past burned DVDs with this device from ubuntu using DVD+R media.  This is the first attempt with Windows 8 inside VirtualBox.

How would I enable access to the `Passthrough` checkbox?  As you can see, it is greyed out.

Selecting the `Machine, Settings, Storage, Controller IDE, Host Drive TSSTcorp DVDWBD` does not seem to enable the checkbox.

Enabling the DVD writer via `Devices, DVD, Host Drive TSSTcorp DVDWBD` also does not enable the checkbox at the `Machine, Settings, Storage` dialog.

It makes no difference whether the drive is loaded with a blank DVD+R or with a previously written one (produced on real Windows machine).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you have to shutdown Windows 8, then go to VirtualBox's `Machine, Settings, Storage` to enable `Passthrough` for the DVD drive.